# Is there a way to execute Neo4j cypher queries indirectly to the graph and get the visual graph back?

Tags: neo4j

I want to be able to connect and execute my Neo4j queries from anywhere, such as sending a script to a client and allowing them to connect through IDE or server where the script lives, execute the queries/script and get the results of the query back as a graph. Id like this to be done without the user having to go browser.

Prefer to use either Python/JS to perform this operation.

A couple of tools that Ive been investigating are: graphistry and Neovis.js, but not sure if these would handle the use case.

Thanks

Comment: Questions that tend to lead to opinion-based answers may be closed by the SO community. It would be better for you to ask a question about a specific framework after having already tried it.

Comment: Aside from this being broad and opinion-based, it's also a recommendation question (also off-topic). Please read [ask], as well as how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Lastly: Please be mindful of tags. While you might ultimately choose to use python or JS, those tags don't (currently) apply to your question. I removed these, accordingly.